# Do greyscale .bmp files store values for r,g, b?

Tags: image-processing, graphics

Looking at [.bmp's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) on wikipedia you can see that providing different header values allows you to specify things such as:

- bit depth
- compression method

but I don't see anything regarding greyscale. I have come across a [function](http://codepad.org/0uldc8Un) for greyscale .bmp images that reads every byte of data, out of the file, as a color value. In other words the following values might represent the first 5 pixels:

```
    {255, 248, 248, 248, 249} // 1 pixel per element, in greyscale
```

I must be wrong about something or missing something because this function does work but it doesn't seem compatible with the definition of a .bmp on Wikipedia.

Comment: An 8-bit indexed bmp can do exactly this by having a greyscale palette, where every entry e.g. 248 maps to RGB(248, 248, 248) etc. In such cases, it's obviously redundant to use the palette although one must exist if the bit depth is <= 8.

Comment: are 8-bit indexed bmp's common or do you have to do something special to make them?

Comment: They used to be much more common when graphics cards had less memory and lower colour resolution. The wiki you linked shows how to make them and there are numerous libraries and applications that will produce them and display them.